# Extract all possible pairs within group in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

Currently, I am struggling with a problem related to obtaining all possible  permutation within group using data.table.

To explain my problem, let me show you an example.

```
x <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
y <- c('red', 'blue', 'black', 'orange', 'red')
dt1 <- as.data.table(cbind(x,y))
dt1
   x      y
1: 1    red
2: 1   blue
3: 1  black
4: 2 orange
5: 2    red
```

Now I want to see every possible pair of color(y) within group(x). So my ideal result would be....

```
x   y1      y2
1   black   blue
1   black   red
1   blue    black
1   blue    red
1   red     black
1   red     blue
2   orange  red
2   red     orange
```

To find a solution for this, I did googling it and I found a function, permutation, which is what I am looking for but I find it hard to squeeze it into data.table framework.

```
y <- c('red', 'blue', 'black')
permutations(n=3, r=2, v=y, repeats.allowed=F)

     [,1]    [,2]   
[1,] "black" "blue" 
[2,] "black" "red"  
[3,] "blue"  "black"
[4,] "blue"  "red"  
[5,] "red"   "black"
[6,] "red"   "blue"
```

So I tried to do the following but obviously it has errors..

```
dt1[, .(j = lapply(.SD, permutations, n=.N, r=2, v=y, repeats.allowed=F)), by=x]
```

Any suggestion for this?
I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Perhaps `dt1[ , CJ(y, y), by = x][V1 != V2]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, don't use `as.data.table(cbind(...))` to create the data table. You will get unexpected column classes due to `cbind` coercing to matrix.  Use

```
dt1 <- data.table(x, y)
```

That said, you can do

```
dt1[, {
        p <- gtools::permutations(.N, 2, y, repeats=FALSE)
        .(y1 = p[, 1], y2 = p[, 2])
    }, by = x]
```

which gives

> ```
>    x     y1     y2
> 1: 1  black   blue
> 2: 1  black    red
> 3: 1   blue  black
> 4: 1   blue    red
> 5: 1    red  black
> 6: 1    red   blue
> 7: 2 orange    red
> 8: 2    red orange
> ```

There is no need to loop since we are operating on groups.  `permutations` creates a matrix, so we create our desired result columns from the resulting matrix columns of `permutations`.